# How to stop processing the problematic record polled from kafka that causes k8s pod to restart

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift, microservices, stateful

What would be the best design/solution to detect the problematic message polled from Kafka topic that causes microservice to crash and restart constantly? It will crash and restart constantly because consumer offset is remembered just after successful message processing. In case of an error offset will not be committed so when the pod crashes and restarts microservice will continue to consume the same problematic one. For example for OutOfMemoryError. Keeping the state could be a solution but then all microservices need to be stateful and it needs to be saved and deleted afterwards for any message, as there is a no/low chance to catch the OutOfMemory. I can not keep the retry number of message in message itself. I need to store it outside the message. I wonder to learn the best practices for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a classic "poisoned pill" problem, your deserializer and consumer should swallow this exception then the offset will be committed and you can move to the next message.

Comment: But if pod gets crashed before being able to swallow? For example when I get OutOfMemoryError pod crashes without being able to catch it and restarts. There should be a smart mechanism to break the circuit in this case to understand the poisoned message.

Comment: An OutOfMemoryError from processing a single message is very strange. I think you should limit the scope of processing your message. What kind of processing are you doing ? If its too much try to divide it by saving it to DB, then have another task to process it, like a step function. Having a long and complex processing of your kafka message is quiet of anti-pattern.

Comment: Actually it was an example. You can catch Exceptions but can't catch the Errors most of the times. I can't keep the number of retry inside the message so I need a solution to be able to store that number of retry outside the message. But what is the best practice for poisoned messages on kafka?

Comment: For number of retries you can keep it in either a dB or cashing mechanism like redis. And generally as I said, catch whatever exception during serializing then return null and in processing skip if null.

Comment: Thanks for your all replies. An error can occur after serialization while processing the message.

Comment: Yup, there also you need to catch it and skip it or so. As soon as your consumer function exits the offset is comitted. @Override
public Collection<T> consume()

Comment: Actually I amsking this one for more the ones that can't be caught like OutOfMEmoryError. There is no guarantee that it will enter the catch block, Pod can kill itself or openshift can kill the pod. No catch block no graceful shutdown so seems like state needs to be stored in somewhere else to handle this case to handle the poison pill